# Send password to new user

Tags: passwords

I would like to ask some questions about password security. In my software the admin can create a new user setting the password and the username. I believe sending the password in plain text in an email is not a very good idea, so I’m thinking about sending a link that redirect the user to a page where they can set up their password. This link should expire after few hours as well. On my login form I’ve also have the option “forgot password” how can I prevent that a user doesn’t use it until they create the new password? How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

A password reset link is technically exactly the same as a registration link, both are relying on the "fact" that only the owner of the email address can read the link. So there is no reason to prevent a password reset when the user did not yet login.

The usual workflow is slightly different though, usually the user makes the first contact with the site and on the register page (s)he is asked to enter a password.